# How to copy List contents inside an attribute of other Lists?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create a copy of the contents of my *List* inside an attribute of the other *dynamic lists*.

[image: Example]

---

I tried to accomplish this with jQuery and I did it as follows:

HTML:

```
<ul class="main">
    <li>Alpha</li>
    <li>Beta</li>
    <li>Gamma</li>
    <li>Delta</li>
</ul>

<ul class="clone">
    <li>content 1</li>
    <li>content 2</li>
    <li>content 3</li>
    <li>content 4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="clone">
    <li>content 1</li>
    <li>content 2</li>
    <li>content 3</li>
    <li>content 4</li>
</ul>
[..etc..]
```

jQuery:

```
var Alpha = $('ul.main li:nth-child(4n+1)').text();
var Beta = $('ul.main li:nth-child(4n+2)').text();
var Gamma = $('ul.main li:nth-child(4n+3)').text();
var Delta = $('ul.main li:nth-child(4n+4)').text();

$('ul.clone li:nth-child(4n+1)').attr('data-content', Alpha);
$('ul.clone li:nth-child(4n+2)').attr('data-content', Beta);
$('ul.clone li:nth-child(4n+3)').attr('data-content', Gamma);
$('ul.clone li:nth-child(4n+4)').attr('data-content', Delta);
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bn6BF/1/)

The problem is that I have to write for every li a `:nth-child()` so to resolve the problem I want to create a **LOOP** for `nth-child(Xn+X)`, because if I have 100 items in the `.main` list I want to clone this 100 items to all other `.clone` lists (that respectively have 100 items) in `data-content`.

Is there a better way to do this dynamically instead of writing **[:nth-child(4n+1)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)** for every li?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions involve looping over the array of contents gathered from `.main`.  There are many possibilities.  You can easily get the contents as an array via `.map`:

```
var contents = $(".main li").map(function () {
    // $(this).text() is more compatible but more expensive
    return this.textContent;
}).get();
```

Then, rather than using `:nth-child` you can get the element's relative index via the `.index` method.

```
$(".clone li").attr("data-content", function () {
    return contents[$(this).index()];
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fKPmc/

Answer (score 1):

this may do:

first we create an array of the targeted values.

```
var contents = $.map($('ul.main li', function(element, index) {
    return $(element).text();
});

console.log(contents);
// => ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta']
```

then we will need one loop on all `ul` with the class `.clone`. for each `ul`, we will loop again on its `li` children and set the value of `data-content` using the index which is matching with the `contents` array that we have set earlier. As long as the mark-up is set the way it is in the question this will work

```
$('ul.clone').each(function(index, ul) {
    $('li', ul).each(function (i, li) {
        $(li).attr('data-content', contents[i]);
    });

});
```

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: How this can help? Please explain.